# Capture Screen Android, but not my App

Tags: android, screen, capture, rootview

Hello everyone I will try to be as clear as possible .... I have a method in which I get the Screen of my App, what I would really like is to be able to use my method to get Screen from other apps, or the Android desktop, The way I try to do it is before I capture the screen, I transform my Layout into INVISIBLE, but my capture goes black, if I capture my app if it comes out perfect, but I want to capture other apps, any ideas? ... I show you my method ..

public void addListenerOnButton4() {

```
    Button btnTakeScreenshot = (Button) findViewById(R.id.share);


    btnTakeScreenshot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            takeScreenshot();
        }
    });
}
public void takeScreenshot() {

    RelativeLayout ln = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.Layout);
    ln.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    Date now = new Date();
    android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", now);

    try {
        // image naming and path  to include sd card  appending name you choose for file
        String mPath = (Environment
                .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment
                        .DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) +File.separator+now+"ScreenShoot.jpg");


        // create bitmap screen capture
        View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        File imageFile = new File(mPath);

        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        int quality = 100;
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

    } catch (Throwable e) {
        // Several error may come out with file handling or OOM
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: On Android 5.0+, you can use the media projection APIs to do this. See [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MediaProjection/andshooter). Prior to that, there is no support for screenshots of other apps, except perhaps on rooted devices or through the use of development tools.

Answer (score 2):

**- API level 21+**

You can use `MediaProjectionManager`. [Details here.](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MediaProjection/andshooter)

`MediaProjection` implementation gives you a `Bitmap` that you can save as JPEG. After you get `byteArray` just write it to the file as you usually do in Java.

```
Bitmap bmp = // your Bitmap here
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

**- API before 21**

Android gives a way to capture only `View` but when you make it `INVISIBLE` there's no color for you `View` anymore. That is why you're getting the black screen. 
You can't take a screenshot of other apps just making your `View` invisible because the capture function connected to the `View`.

**- Any API + root**

If you want to do this anyway you need root access. Then you can read `framebuffer` and get the raw data and convert it into `Bitmap`. [Check details here.](http://www.pocketmagic.net/android-native-screen-capture-application-using-the-framebuffer/#.UTG82TfDs1o)

Comment: Thanks Val for responding, I understand that I should use MediaProjection in fact I have a project in which I record the screen using MediaPoyection, but I do not understand how to take a screenshot and pass it to jpg from MediaProyection, and check the link that you passed but not I find any code that works

Comment: `MediaProjection` implementation gives you a `Bitmap` that you can save as JPEG. I updated the answer. The code works well.